# Verify MenuItem title in test

Tags: android, android-testing

In my activity test I need to verify that a menu item has certain title.

I can get it by ID but it returns a view.

```
final View menuItem = (View) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.do_it);
```

But how can I get the title from this view then?

Note: I need to do it in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test.

### Update

I am hoping to find a way to get menu item's title in my test case without writing any additional code in activity, like storing menu in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getTitle()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.<manuLayout>, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.do_it);
    String title = menuItem.getTitle();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I do it in a test?

Comment: Declare a class variable of type Menu. Initialize the variable in onCreateOptionsMenu. Use this Menu variable anywhere to get title.

Comment: It does work, I wish there was a way to get menu and its title from test without adding additional code to activity class. Thanks.